# Visual Studio 2010: Can't create new connection to SQL Server Compact 4.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I have just installed [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) 4.0 on my Windows 7 machine. (Note that I already had SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 on the machine).

However, in my Visual Studio 2010 project, I am unable to create a new connection to a SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 database... i.e. - by doing the following:

- In Server Explorer, right click "Data Connections"
- "Add Connection"
- "Change Data Source" - Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 not an option (only version 3.5)

How can I make Visual Studio 2010 know about my already installed copy of Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See

- [SQL Server Compact 4.0 Tooling Support in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and Visual Web Developer Express 2010 SP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/03/15/sql-server-compact-4-0-tooling-support-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1-and-visual-web-developer-express-2010-sp1.aspx)

and

- [Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 with support for SQL Server Compact 4.0 released](http://erikej.blogspot.ch/2011/03/visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-with.html)

Do you have VS2010 SP1 installed?

If not - [download it from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)

Comment: Thanks Marc.. terrific links which really helped me with this prob. I am still working through it... Also, I now realize that I had made a big mistake in removing SQL Server Compact 3.5 sp2 from my PC. Apparently, using SSC 4.0 in VS 2010 *requires* that SS 3.5 also be installed.. else it will not integrate / work at all. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/88ece1aa-4868-4c4f-988d-fa41501e4ef8 - this blog has comments written by the developer of toolbox for SSC 4.0.